# Parse Failed using SQL Server Migration Assistant

Tags: mysql, sql, azure

I'm trying to convert a MySQL database to Sql Azure.
When I load the metadata of one of my databases, I get parsing failed error:

> MySql Server Object Collector error: function : pointInPoly
>        Loading SQL definition or parsing failed for function 'pointInPoly'.

the code of the function is :

```
BEGIN         
   DECLARE p POINT;
   DECLARE poly POLYGON;
   DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE pX DECIMAL(9,6);
   DECLARE pY DECIMAL(9,6);
   DECLARE ls LINESTRING;
   DECLARE poly1 POINT;
   DECLARE poly1X DECIMAL(9,6);
   DECLARE poly1Y DECIMAL(9,6);
   DECLARE poly2 POINT;
   DECLARE poly2X DECIMAL(9,6);
   DECLARE poly2Y DECIMAL(9,6);
   DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE result INT(1) DEFAULT 0;

   SET p = GEOMFROMTEXT(in_point);
   SET poly = GEOMFROMTEXT(in_polygon);

   IF ISNULL(p) OR ISNULL(poly) THEN
      RETURN -2;
   END IF;
   SET pX = X(p);
   SET pY = Y(p);
   SET ls = ExteriorRing(poly);
   SET poly2 = EndPoint(ls);
   SET poly2X = X(poly2);
   SET poly2Y = Y(poly2);
   SET n = NumPoints(ls);

   WHILE i<n DO
      SET poly1 = PointN(ls, (i+1));
      SET poly1X = X(poly1);
      SET poly1Y = Y(poly1);
      IF ( ( ( ( poly1X <= pX ) && ( pX < poly2X ) ) || ( ( poly2X <= pX ) && ( pX < poly1X ) ) ) && ( pY > ( poly2Y - poly1Y ) * ( pX - poly1X ) / ( poly2X - poly1X ) + poly1Y ) ) THEN
         SET result = !result;
      END IF;
      SET poly2X = poly1X;
      SET poly2Y = poly1Y;
      SET i = i + 1;
      END WHILE;
   RETURN result;

END
```

What would be better? go with the convertion for all the other data and create a new MSSQL function for pointInPoly or fix the problem on the MySQL end and then do the migration complete ?

Thing is, I'm totally new to MSSQL. Not sure how it works with spatial data type.
The function supposes to return true if a point is inside a polygon, maybe there's a better way to do it on MSSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's native spatial data then use the spatial data datatypes! Windows Azure SQL Databases support spatial data and is a better balanced datatype for what you're doing. to read more about SQL Server, SQL Databases on Azure and spatial data read following : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff759530.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790(v=sql.105).aspx (it's available since SQL 2008 and up)

Comment: that seems like a valid solution in the end. Unfortunately I'm currently in the migration process which have a lot of things to get covered as you can imagine. If I can ease the work of the 'migrate' and **then** enter into spatial data types would be great. I appreciate your suggestion, not exactly the timing I'm in now. Current data it's on MySQL database and types are of varchar for points and mediumtext for polygons so I don't think is 'native'. Sample content: `POINT(-34.892408 -56.161938)`